# Web Workers - do they create actual threads?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have always thought that web workers create separate threads, but today I ran into the spec on w3c website. Below is a citation about web workers:

> This allows for thread-like operation with message-passing as the
>   coordination mechanism.

The question is - if it is  **thread-like**, not actual thread what is an advantage(performance wise) of using this technology?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, web workers create actual threads (or processes, the spec is flexible on this). According to the [Web Workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) specification, when a worker is created the first step is:

> 1. Create a separate parallel execution environment (i.e. a separate thread or process or equivalent construct), and run the rest of these steps in that context.
>
>    For the purposes of timing APIs, this is the official moment of creation of the worker.
>
> (W3C Web Workers specification section 4.4)

So it is explicitly specified that code running in Web Workers run in actual threads or processes.

Although it is possible to implement Workers without threads (note the "equivalent construct" language) for use on systems that don't support threads, all browser implementations implement Web Workers as threads.

Answer (score 1):

A web worker runs in a single thread isolated from the main thread, the way they pass messages around is **thread-like** and works differently depending on whether you're using dedicated (can only be accessed from the script that created it) or shared (can be accessed by any script within the same domain via a port object) workers.

EDIT:
Updated answer to reflect my comment from months ago. While a SINGLE web worker runs in an isolated thread it doesn't mean each additional worker will run in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks! Is this "single isolated thread" dedicated just for web workers? Separate from UI thread?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode does single isolated thread mean there's just one thread for all workers?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode So using multiple workers has no benefit.

Comment: @TomášZato sorry I think I miscommunicated my answer, it will spawn a single thread for all workers each being isolated from the main UI thread.

Comment: @TomášZato The general idea is not to run too many workers simultaneously as there is no hard limit set on the amount you can spawn and they can quickly eat up the system resources of your users.

Comment: Please add some reference to your answer. I'm rather unsure where did you reach the information you provided.

Comment: @TomášZato Paraphrased from MDN.

Comment: To be clear: all multithreaded programs run each thread in a single isolated thread isolated from the main thread. Singlethreaded programs on the other hand run all code in the main thread. So yes, webworkers are multithreaded. What they are not however are shared memory. Webworkers are designed around the message passing paradigm which is one way you can structure multithreaded programs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API),

> Web Workers are a mechanism by which a script operation can be made to run in a **background thread separate from the main execution thread** of a web application. The advantage of this is that laborious processing can be performed in a separate thread, allowing the main (usually the UI) thread to run without being blocked/slowed down.

So, each worker does not create a separate thread, but all workers are running in a single separate thread.

I guess, like just in other things, the implementation and approach may differ from browser to browser.

Comment: @andrey It looks like they do not.

Comment: I think this answer is just one possible interpretation of the MDN content. It is not clear of *background thread separate from the main execution thread* refers to thread per `Worker` instance, or thread per browser process. However both interpretations are possible.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: Each webworker runs in their own thread. Read the MDN text carefully: "by which ***a*** script operation can be made to run in a background thread". Not ***all*** script operation. But each one script operation run in their own thread.