# New Webworker or postMessage which one will create new Thread every time

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

To get the new thread using the Web worker, do We need to create new worker object for every complex calculation which I do?

Or I can create only one worker object and just post Message to the worker JavaScript file?

Assume I have to calculate something for 3 different inputs, the calculation logic is same but the input will be different.

Do I need to create 3 new worker objects or I can create only one worker and just post 3 different message to get 3 independent threads to do the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your requirements.

3 new worker threads will do calculations in parallel.

3 different messages posted to the same worker thread instance will do calculations in sequence these messages were posted. Note: you still need one web worker in this case in order these calculations to do not block your UI.

Comment: I would like to do 3 different threads do the calculation in parallel . So I will create 3 worker objects then.                                                                                                       Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SrinivasanDuraisamy Keep in mind that there can be only as much parallel processing as there's processor cores. Also some people seem to claim all workers run in one thread, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33776530/607407